# eBay API - How to include affiliate tracking information in GetItem call's ViewItemURL parameter

Tags: ebay-api, affiliate

As far I know some eBay API call like:

1. [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request)
2. [getSimilarItems](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/callref/getSimilarItems.html#Request)

have an input parameter to specify the Affiliate `trackingId`, `networkId` and other info that allow me to identify my affiliate and then return a `ViewItemURL` that have included affiliate tracking information.

How do I pass my affiliate data to the API call [GetItem](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html#Response.Item.ListingDetails.ViewItemURL), so its response field `ViewItemURL` has included my affiliate tracking information?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `GetSingleItem` call in the Shopping API rather than `GetItem` in the Trading API?

> GetSingleItem 
>   http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html

It does the exact same job, and it allows URL parameters in the call to be used to "affiliatise" the returned URL.

> http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#AffiliateURLParameters